# In command line, what does "python file.py shell" do?

Tags: python, django, shell

I have run into a Django tutorial where the instructor is running `python manage.py shell`.

This yields:

```
(env) MBP:Project user$ python3 manage.py shell

Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```

Couple questions:

1. What does `shell` do in `python manage.py shell`?
2. What does `(InteractiveConsole)` in the above mean ? I don't see this when I run `python` without the `shell`. I have googled InteractiveConsole to no avail.
3. What is "being done" to `manage.py` here? Is it being "run" or "served"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you run `python manage.py shell` you run a python (or IPython) interpreter but inside it load all your Django project configurations so you can execute commands against the database or any other resources that are available in your Django project.
2. If you run `python manage.py` you only display all the options available to use with the 'manage.py' script in your project (like runserver or migrate)
3. In the shell, your project is not running as a http service but you can perform operations like querying the database or calling internal functions.

Comment: 3 for 3! Thank you very much

Comment: If I may ask it here, do you know how to achieve the same from within a module? I would like to write some automation code to update tables in Django from a python module, i.e. a script that starts by loading all the Django project configs and then I can interact with the databases.

Comment: In django this is called a custom command, there is a section about it in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/